# I am passing list values to my jqplot stacked bar chart but no chart is displyed

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, jsp, jqplot

I have stored values in 3 columns of the  database  then using list(collections) i am able to display it on my table using jsp. Now i have written the code to generate stacked bar chart on the same jsp page but i am not able to display it as stacked bar chart. 
Here is my jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*,javax.*" %>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page import="com.rajesh.action.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>January</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Report for January</h1>

<body>
<table border="1" >
<tr>
<th>Market</th>
<th>Jan-01</th>
<th>Jan-02</th>
<th>Jan-03</th>
<th>Jan-04</th>
<th>Jan-05</th>
<th>Jan-06</th>
<th>Jan-07</>
<th>Jan-08</>
<th>Jan-09</>
<th>Jan-10</>
<th>Jan-11</>
<th>Jan-12</>
<th>Jan-13</>
<th>Jan-14</>
<th>Jan-15</>
<th>Jan-16</>
<th>Jan-17</>
<th>Jan-18</>
<th>Jan-19</>
<th>Jan-20</>
<th>Jan-21</>
<th>Jan-22</>
<th>Jan-23</>
<th>Jan-24</>
<th>Jan-25</>
<th>Jan-26</>
<th>Jan-27</>
<th>Jan-28</>
<th>Jan-29</>
<th>Jan-30</>
<th>Jan-31</>
</tr>

<tr>
<td rowspan="3">AUK</>
<c:forEach items="${abc}" var="item">
<td>${item.count}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>
<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc}" var="item">
<td>${item.dataamount}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc}" var="item">
<td>${item.result}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<td rowspan="3">AUS</td>
<c:forEach items="${abc1}" var="item1">
<td>${item1.count}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc1}" var="item1">
<td>${item1.dataamount}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc1}" var="item1">
<td>${item1.result}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<td rowspan="3">ADE</td>
<c:forEach items="${abc2}" var="item2">
<td>${item2.count}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>
<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc2}" var="item2">
<td>${item2.dataamount}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc2}" var="item2">
<td>${item2.result}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr> 

<tr>
<td rowspan="3">Ebay</td>
<c:forEach items="${abc3}" var="item3">
<td>${item3.count}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>


<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc3}" var="item3">
<td>${item3.dataamount}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc3}" var="item3">
<td>${item3.result}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr> 

<tr>
<td rowspan="3">Play</td>
<c:forEach items="${abc4}" var="item4">
<td>${item4.count}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc4}" var="item4">
<td>${item4.dataamount}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr>

<tr>
<c:forEach items="${abc4}" var="item4">
<td>${item4.result}</td>
</c:forEach>
</tr> 

</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.canvasOverlay.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.highlighter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.cursor.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/excanvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/excanvas.min.js"></script>
<link href="plugins/jquery.jqplot.css"  rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="plugins/jquery.jqplot.min.css"  rel="stylesheet" />
<body>

<span id="info3">Nothing yet.</span>
<div id="chart3" style="height:900px;width:1300px; "></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var s1 = [];
var s2 = [];
var s3 = [];

<c:forEach var="temp" items="${abc}">
s1.push('${item.result}');
</c:forEach>

<c:forEach var="temp" items="${abc}">
s2.push('${item.count}');
</c:forEach>

<c:forEach var="temp" items="${abc}">
s3.push('${item.dataamount}');
</c:forEach>




var axisDates = ["Jan 1", "Jan 2", "Jan 3","Jan 4","Jan 5","Jan 6","Jan 7","Jan  8","Jan 9","Jan 10","Jan 11","Jan 12","Jan 13","Jan 14","Jan 15","Jan 16","Jan 17","Jan  18","Jan 19","Jan 20","Jan 21","Jan 22","Jan 23","Jan 24","Jan 25","Jan 26","Jan  27","Jan28","Jan 29","Jan 30","Jan 31"]


plot3 = $.jqplot('chart3', [s1, s2, s3], {

stackSeries: true,
varyBarColor: true,


captureRightClick: true,

animate : !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
seriesDefaults : {
renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
rendererOptions: {
barPadding : 20, 


barMargin : 25, 

barDirection : 'vertical',
barWidth : 30,

shadowOffset : 4,
highlightMouseOver: true   
}, 
pointLabels: {show: true}
},
axes: {xaxis: {
renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer, ticks: axisDates

},
yaxis: {min:0, max: 2300

}
},

legend: {
show: true,
location: 'e',
placement: 'outside'
}     
});
  // Bind a listener to the "jqplotDataClick" event.  Here, simply change
  // the text of the info3 element to show what series and ponit were
  // clicked along with the data for that point.
$('#chart3').bind('jqplotDataClick',
function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
$('#info3').html('series: '+seriesIndex+', point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data);
}
);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @omar yea its duplicate but i have not got answer for that. so i raised again.

Comment: A few people will answer your questions if you act like this. Don't be in a hurry and add more informations about what you have done so far : do you get errors? any informations get from a debugger?

Comment: thank you for replying.. i dont get errors but the thing is it is stacked bar chart  so only 2 values are showing up and the third bar is not showing only. I have updated my code. please check

Comment: An obvious question : are you sure not to have s3 as an empty array?

Comment: It's not allowed to ask the same question if you get no answer. You could ask any user kindly to set 50 bounty to get others attention. If you still need help, let me know I'll set a bounty for your original question.

Comment: please set me a bounty :( @Omar

Comment: @AnthonyLeGovic S3 is not empty at all...i have checked it.

Comment: You need to wait for 2 days.

Comment: thank you for ur help..actually wat it is..first time i am hearing

Comment: Do you have a link where we can see what happens? Or an exemple on Fiddle or another similar website?

Comment: does fiddle supports java?

Comment: jsfiddle.net yes it does. I cant set a bounty on a new question, after two days the system allows bounties.